# Ember oneWay Binding not working as expected

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller, that serves a default- *production* of a model to a template

```
activeProduction: Ember.computed('model.productions', function() {
    // as default serve first Production
    return this.get('model.productions').get('firstObject');
}),
```

In this *production*-model i have a property 'settings' that I want to be modified temporarily, without affecting the actual value in the store, so I made a computed oneWay property for those settings:

```
productionSettingsComputed: Ember.computed.oneWay('activeProduction.settings'),
```

Those settings are accessed and changed in a template like this:

```
saved Settings:<br>
{{activeProduction.settings.startMonday}}<br>
computed oneWay Settings:<br>
{{productionSettingsComputed.startMonday}}<br>

{{form/check-box checked=productionSettingsComputed.startMonday label='Overview and month always start on a Monday'}}
```

*(the form/checkbox is just a custom component wrapping a default ember-form-checkbox)*

I now expected that if I change the value in the checkbox, that only the second value (`{{productionSettingsComputed.startMonday}}`) changes. But also the 'stored' value in `{{activeProduction.settings.startMonday}}` is changing.
So that 'oneWay' isn't realy only oneWay.

Am I misunderstanding something, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Yes, I know, that I could do a work around with discarding changes later, but this would give me headaches about user-rights and other stuff...

*(Emberjs 2.5)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dereference `productionSettingsComputed`, so `{{activeProduction.settings.startMonday}}` and `{{productionSettingsComputed.startMonday}}` evaluate to the same `startMonday`.

You would need to alias the `startMonday` property:

```
// model:
startMondayComputed: Ember.computed.oneWay('activeProduction.settings.startMonday'),

// template:
saved Settings:<br>
{{activeProduction.settings.startMonday}}<br>
computed oneWay Settings:<br>
{{startMondayComputed}}<br>

{{form/check-box checked=startMondayComputed label='Overview and month always start on a Monday'}}
```

Comment: Yes, this is working as expected, thanks. It's not as handy as I hoped, because now I have to hardcode this for like 20 differnt 'settings'...